# How to expand a double sum of products express?

Tags: calculus, algebra-precalculus, summation, finance

Specifically, I need to expand this *unexpected loss for a portfolio* expression in order to calculate:

$$S=\sqrt{(\sum_{i=1}^2\sum_{j=1}^2 w_i w_j u_i u_j ρ_{ij})}$$

I've attempted to expand it on my own, coming up with:

$$\sqrt{(w_i*w_i*u_i*u_i*ρ_{ij} + w_j*w_j*u_j*u_j*ρ_{ij})}$$

Am I expanding this expression correctly?

Thanks!

Comment: what are the lower bounds and upper bounds of the indeces $i$ and $j$?

Comment: 1 to 2 (it's a 2 asset portfolio)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all the variables which do not depend on j can be written in front of the second sigma sign.

$$S=\sqrt{\sum_{i=1}^2 w_iu_i \sum_{j=1}^2  w_j u_j ρ_{ij}}$$

Now you write the summands of the second sigma sign with the different values (1,2) of $j$. The index $i$ remains $i$.

$$S=\sqrt{\sum_{i=1}^2 w_iu_i \left(w_1u_1\rho_{i1}+w_2u_2\rho_{i2}\right)}$$

Multiplying out the brackets

$$S=\sqrt{\sum_{i=1}^2 \left( w_iu_i w_1u_1\rho_{i1}+w_iu_iw_2u_2\rho_{i2}\right)}$$

The variables without the index i can be written in front of the sigma sign again.

$$S=\sqrt{w_1u_1\sum_{i=1}^2 w_iu_i \rho_{i1}+w_2u_2\sum_{i=1}^2w_iu_i\rho_{i2}}$$

$$S=\sqrt{w_1u_1 w_1u_1 \rho_{11}+w_1u_1 w_2u_2 \rho_{21}+w_2u_2w_1u_1\rho_{12}+w_2u_2w_2u_2\rho_{22}}$$

Two some facts about $\rho_{xy}$

1.$\rho_{11}=\rho_{22}=1$

2.$\rho_{12}=\rho_{21}$

Thus finally we get

$$S=\sqrt{w_1^2u_1^2 +2w_1u_1 w_2u_2 \rho_{21}+w_2^2u_2^2}$$

Comment: You're the best! Thank you for this!!!

Comment: @tyler You´re welcome.